# Sublime Text autocomplete window closes when scrolling off the list

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

When scrolling the autocomplete list with <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>down</kbd>, if you go too far in either direction (e.g. there are no more suggestions), the list will close.

The behavior I want is to have the list wrap when reaching the end instead of close.

This is easy to fix with downward scrolling by assigning this hotkey:

```
{ "keys": ["down"], "command": "auto_complete", "context":
    [ { "key": "auto_complete_visible" } ]
},
```

That's because the `auto_complete` command has built-in functionality to scroll downward each time it's invoked, which is why the hotkey works.

...But upward scrolling is different. I've tried about 20 different hotkey and macro combinations with no success.

I'm almost certain the only way to achieve this behavior is with a plugin, but unfortunately my Python skill level is nil.

If it matters, I'm manually invoking autocomplete with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (the automatic popup is disabled).

I'm using Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Please let me know when you try the plugin.

Comment: I have just tested it and it also works on Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'll try your plugin this afternoon. If it's good, I'll slide these 50 points your way. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Now there's a good and easy way of doing it using the new `auto_complete_cycle` setting. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Best solution: use *auto_complete_cycle* settings (added 26 March 2015):**

### Please use this new simple solution and not the python plugin

Sublime Text new version relased on 24 March 2015 has a new **setting called *auto_complete_cycle*** that implement this behaviour. Set it to true to iterate through the autocomplete results.

```
"auto_complete_cycle": true
```

**Worst old solution: this custom plugin**

I have just made this plugin that works well on *Sublime Text 3* in *Linux Mint*. I have not tested it in *Sublime Text 2* but think the plugin system it's the same, so, it should work on that version too. The workaround used it's not too pretty but works.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class UpArrowInAutoCompleteCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.settings().set('autoCompleteFlag',True)
        self.view.settings().set('initialPoint', self.view.sel()[0].begin())

        """ Move one line up """
        self.view.run_command('move', {"by": "lines", "forward": False});
        """ Auto-complete was opened and up arrow was pressed, so if the cursor changes
        (on_selection_modified will be triggered) we have gone outside the list. 
        If we were not in the first element on_selection_modified will not be triggered, so
        we turn of the flag"""
        sublime.set_timeout(lambda: self.view.settings().set('autoCompleteFlag', False),300)


class AutoCompleteSelectionModifiedTriggerCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_selection_modified(self, view):
        if view.settings().get('autoCompleteFlag'):
            """ If the up arrow was pressed and on_selection_modified 
            has been triggered, then we know that we were in the first element
            of the list and we hitted the up arrow"""
            view.settings().set('autoCompleteFlag', False)
            initialPoint = view.settings().get('initialPoint')

            """ We don't know how many words the auto_complete has, so, 
            in order to calculate that number, we move down in the list
            till we get outside the list. After that we make the list appear
            again and move down n-1 times to go (and stay) to the last line """
            view.sel().clear()
            view.sel().add(initialPoint)
            view.run_command('auto_complete')

            numLines = 0
            while view.sel()[0].begin() == initialPoint:
                view.run_command('move', {"by": "lines", "forward": True})
                numLines += 1
                if numLines == 401:
                    return

            if numLines == 0:
                return

            view.sel().clear()
            view.sel().add(initialPoint)
            view.run_command('auto_complete')

            numLine = 0
            while numLine < (numLines-1):
                view.run_command('move', {"by": "lines", "forward": True})
                numLine += 1
```

To make the plugin use *Tools>new Plugin* and paste the code. Then save it in *Packages/User* folder. You can use *Preferences>Browse Packages* to find the *Packages* floder, inside which the User folder is located.

To make it work I added to my *user key-bindings file* this bindings (the second it's your own binding):

```
{
    "keys": ["up"],
    "command": "up_arrow_in_auto_complete",
    "context": [{
        "key": "auto_complete_visible",
        "operator": "equal",
        "operand": true
    }]
}, {
    "keys": ["down"],
    "command": "auto_complete",
    "context": [{
        "key": "auto_complete_visible"
    }]
}
```

Edit: this is an example result:

[image: Result]

Comment: It didn't work. I tried Sublime Text 2.0.1 and 2.0.2, both x86 and x64 versions (4 different versions total). Once the up-scroll was supposed to wrap, the cursor disappeared and Sublime Text required a mouse-click to regain focus. Here are two error messages that were produced: [error-pic-1](http://imgur.com/T5TDt8a), [error-pic-2](http://imgur.com/gJwaRWI#0).

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that error (tested in ST2.0.2 x64 on windows 7 and ST3 x64 on Linux Mint). So, when you are in the first element of the list and press the up arrow, the list nevers wrap? Or the list doesn't wrap only when that error window appears? Have you tried disabling the setting the second pic talks about?

Comment: I'll definitely give it another try when I find a free moment. The second pic is describing THIS plugin. I wouldn't mind hearing feedback from anyone else who has tried it. Two upvotes so far tells me the problem is mine, somehow.

Comment: It works with 2.0.2! My problem was with 2.0.1 (both x86 and x64). I tried 2.0.2, but from a sandbox, which was probably my problem. Since I'm still using 2.0.1, it's time to upgrade. I hate upgrading. Thanks for your effort, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it finally worked :D. You're welcome.

Comment: Plus 1 - for  the image example, this gives a hint what the answer is about