# Sublime how to cycle through the completion?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I found that `tab` can't cycle through completion like in Vim

then i search for other way of cycling through completion and many says that `ctrl+space` is available for this

however this doesn't work on me either, so i wonder if sublime has any way to do this

version: Sublime Text 3

many thanks!

Comment: what does auto_complete in Preference/FileSetting say?

Comment: Try adding/setting this "tab_completion": True    to your Preferences/File Settings - User:

Comment: @Stiffo that is for setting whether complete with the first entry after closed the completion panel

Comment: @therealprashant I suppose that auto_complete doesn't affect this problem

Comment: If I understand well your problem is that you can't jump from the first to the last result nor from the last to the first result of the autocomplete list. I think you mean that when you say 'cicle', is that right?

Comment: kind of switch to the second entry, e.g.: I got "def" and "defs" in my completion list, and i want to select "defs" without using ↓

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use <kbd>tab</kbd> in order to move down in the autocomplete list you only need to create the proper key-binding. You can get the desired info from the <kbd>down</kbd> key key-binding. Example:

```
{
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "move",
    "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true},
    "context":
        [
            { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ]
}
```

Note the context to avoid that tab moves by lines in other contexts.

**EDIT**: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263791/sublime-text-autocomplete-window-closes-when-scrolling-off-the-list) contains info about how to enable autocomplete cycle (jump from last to first entry and from first to last).

Comment: thanks! but this cannot goes back, which i means circle the list that you goes back to the first entry after selected the last

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263791/sublime-text-autocomplete-window-closes-when-scrolling-off-the-list) for info about how to enable autocomplete cycle (jump from last to first and from first to last).

Comment: this is exactly what i want:D appreciate for that!